# Is it possible to set a proxy chain with Selenium Webdriver Python?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, fingerprint

I want to change fingerprint of selenium webriver with python for test purpose. After doing my research I found I can use Browsermob-proxy to achieve that. But I am already using Tor proxy. Can I combined those two as a pipe like a proxy chain for changing my http headers sent by selenium webdriver ?